# Dynamically construct field of type URL from fixed + <fieldvalue> elements

Tags: url

I have a field defined as a url, however the URL is actually made up of a standard URL to our document managment system and the document number which is what the user enters.  How do I get the formula for this field to concatenate the standard URL part with the 6 character number field the user types in which represents the document nuber to be retrieved from our system?  So in the end the URL looks like 
'http://www.ourURL.com/applications/DMSRouter/3596560'  Where the number at the end is what the user types into the field.  I am trying to use the concatenate function but how do I reference the current value of the field (ie the numebr part)?

Comment: What do you mean by current? do you mean on edit screen as soon as user enter document number?

Comment: Yes, pretty much, or at aleast once its saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a way - using a workflow rule. The workflow rule can update the field that triggers it. So by using this formula in the update step of the workflow rule I get a close to deisred effect;

"http://www.ourURL.com/applications/DMSRouter/" & right(Trim(DMS_Number__c),7)

However the editing experience could be prone to typos as the edit window only shows the 1st 3rd of the field and the user has to navigate to the end of the line to change the number.

Comment: Does this render as a clickable hyperlink? Across browsers?

Comment: I have the field type as a URL & it renders as a clickable hyperlink, don't see why it wouldn't work on any browser or do you mean something else?.

Answer (score 1):

ok. In case of saved record you can use any field from the same object in formula. E.g.

'http://www.ourURL.com/applications/DMSRouter/3596560' & 'Doc_number__c' in formula text.

This should give you the required link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "3596560" is the dynamic document ID, and that you want a clickable link rather than just text of a URL, your formula would be:

`HYPERLINK("DMS Link","http://www.ourURL.com/applications/DMSRouter/" & Doc_number__c)`

Comment: Thomas, the problem is that i'm trying to make the field the number is on (in your answer it would be the Doc_number__c field) the clickable field. The default value formula box won't allow me to reference the field i am working on, ie reference itself. I can certainly have 2 fields, one with the number and one with the link constructed using the value from the 1st field. But is there a way to do it all in the one field?

Comment: Not in the standard UI. You could do it in Visualforce, but that seems unnecessarily complicated for this requirement.